# After renew Expired SharePoint Workflow Manager Certificate, WFM Backend Service keep stopping

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, workflow-manager

Three days ago, our workflow manager certificate expired after the initial installation 5 years ago. We tried several ways to renew it but failed. Finally, we set the server date back and was able to renew it. Get -WFFarm, Get -SBFarm is able to return with the right thumbprint information, and previously it shows an error. However after this, the workflow manager backend service keep stopping whenever a workflow is triggered. And we can't find many useful information in the logs. Is there a way to renew the expired license, or we have to re-install it? If we have to reinstall it, how can we keep all the existing data/forms/workflows to ensure no impact to the historical records?